# MySQL replication with masters and slaves in different Kubernetes clusters using Calico as CNI plugin

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, calico

I have a Kubernetes cluster in which there are some MySQL databases.

I want to have a replication slave for each database in a different Kubernetes cluster in a different datacenter.

I'm using Calico as CNI plugin.

To make the replication process work, the slaves must be able to connect to the port 3306 of the master servers. And I would prefer to keep these connections the most isolated as possible.

I'm wondering about the best approach to manage this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to implement your idea is to use a new tool called [Submariner](https://submariner.io/).

Submariner enables direct networking between pods in different Kubernetes clusters on prem or in the cloud.

This new solution overcomes barriers to connectivity between Kubernetes clusters and allows for a host of new multi-cluster implementations, **such as database replication within Kubernetes across geographic regions and deploying service mesh across clusters.**

Key features of Submariner include:

Compatibility and connectivity with existing clusters: Users can deploy Submariner into existing Kubernetes clusters, with the addition of Layer-3 network connectivity between pods in different clusters.

Secure paths: Encrypted network connectivity is implemented using IPSec tunnels.
Various connectivity mechanisms: While IPsec is the default connectivity mechanism out of the box, Rancher will enable different inter-connectivity plugins in the near future.

Centralized broker : Users can register and maintain a set of healthy gateway nodes.

Flexible service discovery: Submariner provides service discovery across multiple Kubernetes clusters.

**CNI compatibility**: Works with popular CNI drivers such as Flannel and **Calico**.

[Prerequisites](https://github.com/rancher/submariner#prerequisites) to use it:

At least 3 Kubernetes clusters, one of which is designated to serve as the central broker that is accessible by all of your connected clusters; this can be one of your connected clusters, but comes with the limitation that the cluster is required to be up in order to facilitate inter-connectivity/negotiation

Different cluster/service CIDR's (as well as different Kubernetes DNS suffixes) between clusters. This is to prevent traffic selector/policy/routing conflicts.

Direct IP connectivity between instances through the internet (or on the same network if not running Submariner over the internet). Submariner supports 1:1 NAT setups, but has a few caveats/provider specific configuration instructions in this configuration.

Knowledge of each cluster's network configuration

Helm version that supports crd-install hook (v2.12.1+)

You can find more info with installation steps on [submariner github](https://github.com/rancher/submariner).
Also, you may find [rancher submariner multi-cluster article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/03/rancher-submariner-multicluster) interesting and useful.

Good luck.

Comment: Very interesting project. I was unaware of it. It looks like the kind of approach I was looking for. Thanks!